# Adding an attribute to a django model, which did not exist previously

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration

I created Django model for my application. It had some attributes, such as title, description, etc.
Then I wanted to add 'slug' of the title, so from My Project it shall be my-project. But my already created model instances do not have these attributes.

I tried just basically adding the attribute as, but it created something like: djangodbmodelsfieldscharfield. I also tried doing it with saving, but it only created this attribute to the newly added model instances

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

# create p1

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = slugify(title)

# create p2

# p1.slug, p2.slug -> 'djangodbmodelsfieldscharfield'

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if not self.id:
             # Only set the slug when the object is created.
             self.slug = slugify(self.title)
         super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

# create p3

# p1.slug, p2.slug -> AttributeError
# p3.slug -> my-title-in-desired-form
```

So my goal would be to create this attribute to every instance in the database. Is it possible, or how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the slug to your model, something like this:

```
slug = models.SlugField(_("Slug"), max_length=150, blank=True)
```

Them, as you have worked out already, you need to set it in the `save` method using slugify.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Location, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.slug = slugify(f"{self.title} {str(self.id)}")
        super(Location, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

That should work. Of course, adding this after the fact means you need to back populate the new field on old records. I actually need to do something similar, and found this to help me out : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/09/26/how-to-create-django-data-migrations.html

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. The tutorial is perfect.